# Using Android Studio v HedgeHog. Thinking I need to disable loading of the emulator. How to do?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a raw Android newb but have years of coding experience in other areas.
I am now stumbling around in Android dev tutorials.
I installed Android Studio and got a pixel5 emulator to work.
Now I'm trying to follow a simple Jetpack Compose tutorial that uses the Preview window but this Hello World app doesn't show up in either Preview or emulator.
I'm getting the feeling that Preview wont work while the emulator is loaded.  Do they conflict?

I was going to try to change the Run config to temporarily disallow the loading of the emulator.  ChatGPT tells me there's a checkbox to do that but I can't find it.

Any tips or hints may help.
Thanks!

I was expecting my Hello World to show up in the Preview window or the emulator or both.
It shows up in neither.

Comment: The emulator is a "real" virtual Android device. The preview is just a simple visualization of a layout that very fast reaches the end of it's capabilities.

Comment: @Robert
I catch your drift that having the emulator working is more important.
Thank you.  Good tip.

Comment: Regarding that the app does not start you should describe in details what works (e.g., project compilation, APK installation to emulator, app start. Usually Android Studio prints  a lot of text logs, copy the text part where it fails to clipboard and paste it into your question.